# Is the number of Jews killed during the Babylonian exile according to Gittin literally true?

Tags: sources-mekorot, history, maseches-gitin, literalism, babylonian-exile

Since the only authoritative sources of information, in this case, seem to be the Jewish Scriptures, can you help *understand* them?

> ... in this valley Nebuzaradan the captain of the guard killed two
>   hundred and eleven myriads, and in Jerusalem he killed ninety-four
>   myriads on one stone ... / [*Babylonian Talmud, Gittin 57a*](http://dtorah.com/otzar/shas_soncino.php?ms=Gittin&df=57b)

The word 'myriad', among other, has its *original* meaning, of *'ten thousand'*, derived from [*Greek*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=myriad) ...

Is this portion of the text, from the Talmud, to be understood *literally*? I.e. '*he killed two million one hundred and ten thousand and nine hundred and forty thousand*' (2.110.000 & 940.000) respectively, or should it not be taken literally? ... Are there any other Jewish Scripture sources that inform on the subject? Thank you